# what is npm cache clean --force --unsafe-perm

Tags: node.js, npm

While creating react js project with
npx create-react-app testproject

I got the following error

`Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, open /Users/username/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/cb/f5/5167796b1df601b21f55bcc456b993154cc89759e4da4e7dabdc82aa83ad`

and I run the 
npm cache clean `--force`, `--unsafe-perm`
it worked, but what exactly it means 
Can someone explain it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All data that passes through the cache is fully verified for integrity on both insertion and extraction. Cache corruption will either trigger an error, or signal to pacote that the data must be refetched, which it will do automatically. For this reason, it should never be necessary to clear the cache for any reason other than reclaiming disk space, thus why clean now requires --force to run.

Please follow the link for more info

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache.html

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following to fix permissions:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```

then you can run:

```
npx create-react-app testproject
```

Other wise you can just run :

```
sudo npx create-react-app testproject
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have root permission e.g. Sudo for ubuntu